# Solving an inequality with conditions on the values

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, inequalities, systems-biology

I have to know if an equation is always negative for the realistic set of values that I'm looking at. The problem is that the equation is way too big. I know I can do it manually if I spend a couple of hours looking at it but it seems something that Mathematica should be able to do it by itself.

I have 12 variables, but they are always between 0 and 1 (except for 2, that always have values above 1). I tried to use Reduce with some conditions to solve this, but it is taking forever to give any output.

Any suggestions on how to solve this? I would put the equation here, but it's a bit too big.

Comment: NMaximize will try and find a global maximum, although it may only find a local solution, and can incorporate the constraints.

Comment: You might want to try using [`Refine`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Refine.html)